# How to recreate an activity in instrumented tests without non-configuration instance being saved?

Tags: android, testing, android-activity

So here is the deal. I know about `ActivityScenario.recreateActivity()`. It perfectly reproduces the configuration change case, when all the non-configuration instance from `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` (say ViewModelStore) is passed into the new activity.

But how would one test the case when the activity is fully destroyed and recreated just from the `savedInstanceState` bundle? I want ViewModelStore to be erased, and ideally, savedInstanceState Bundle to be parceled/unparceled. Similar to when the "Don't keep activities" flag is enabled in Developer options or when the whole process is killed/recreated.

I've looked around but really stuck with this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've created a workaround for the desired behaviour, but I'm still looking for a proper solution.

What I've done in the meantime, is that I'm just manually clearing an activity's ViewModelStore when the activity is destroyed:

```
UiThreadStatement.runOnUiThread {
    scenario.onActivity { 
        it.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                (owner as ComponentActivity).viewModelStore.clear()
            }
        })
    }
}
scenario.recreate()
```

This simulates the full activity recreation and is enough for testing purposes.